# How to locate (& remove) MFC dependent code in a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, migration

I've got a huge legacy project which uses MFC and COM. The idea being to migrate it to Linux (winelib doesn't work for this), I need to identify the portions of the code that use MFC. Strange thing is that the solution contains two DLL projects which inherit from CWinApp and instantiate it. Besides, I don't see the purpose of CWinApp in these DLL's because the actual GUI code is in a separate non-dll project.

Two questions:
1. Is there any tool which can help me locate the MFC specific code so that I can remove it? Already saw the [Qt option](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-walkthrough.html#5-1).
2. Why is CWinApp instantiated (as below) in a DLL project which isn't doing any GUI work at all? Is it used for message passing? I don't see any such syntax though. Removing the CWinApp instantiation results in a pointer of another project not being initialized. Weird!

One of the DLL project's code goes like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <initguid.h>
#include "dlldatax.h"
//removed some project-specific includes for posting on SO

#ifdef _MERGE_PROXYSTUB
extern "C" HINSTANCE hProxyDll;
#endif

CComModule _Module;

BEGIN_OBJECT_MAP(ObjectMap)
OBJECT_ENTRY(CLSID_MyManager, CMyManager)
//removed some other similar lines as the line above
END_OBJECT_MAP()

// Component Category Helper Functions
static HRESULT CreateComponentCategory( CATID catid, WCHAR* catDescription );
static HRESULT UnRegisterCategory( CATID catid );

class CMyClassWrapperApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyClassWrapperApp, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CMyClassWrapperApp theApp;

BOOL CMyClassWrapperApp::InitInstance()
{
#ifdef _MERGE_PROXYSTUB
    hProxyDll = m_hInstance;
#endif
    _Module.Init(ObjectMap, m_hInstance, &LIBID_MyClassWrapperLib);
    return CWinApp::InitInstance();
}

int CMyClassWrapperApp::ExitInstance()
{
    _Module.Term();
    return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}
```

Comment: See here for an answer to your question 2.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c674tx(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yup, had seen that page. But it doesn't explain why the CWinApp is required. Just says it's compulsory to include. So I presume my only option is to take all the non-MFC code out and put it into a new project? No way to remove the MFC portion of the existing DLL project, right?

Comment: Have you tried running the project with Wine? Not winelib, but simply running the exe "as is" under wine.

Comment: A person more expert than me had tried it with Wine but it didn't work. The project is a huge one with many exe's, dependencies on other libraries and many dll's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In your MFC project settings, change to `Use of MFC` to **Use
   Standard Windows Libraries**. Then remove all includes starting with
   'afx' from your `StdAfx.h`. The compilation errors will guide you to
   all MFC specific parts!
2. `CWinApp` is there to allow your MFC executable to correctly use any MFC code in your DLL. The framework will initialize your DLL through this object. For non-MFC DLLs you would just use `DllMain`.

Regarding `COM` and no MFC, I would start by googling this: `atl com codeproject`

Comment: On an added note, there's also this: http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 1):

For me Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition:

1. Project Menu -> Properties -> Advanced -> Use of MFC -> Use Standard Windows Libraries
2. There might be [D8016 '/ZI' and '/Gy-'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462055/3219553) error to be taken care.
3. And yes after that everything went according to the answer above: "Then remove all includes starting with 'afx' from your StdAfx.h. The compilation errors will guide you to all MFC specific parts!"