# Visual Studio error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am having an issue with a project that I am working on. Despite the fact that the code is right, I can't build it because I got the following error

> Error  D8016   '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible  LoadReport  C:\LoadReport\LoadReport\cl

My version of the visual studio is 2015. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I ran into this in Visual Studio 2017 by trying to compile one of Petzold's code samples for windows. I wonder if this always happens when you upgrade old .dsw solutions (VC++6) to .sln.

Comment: @jrh Could be...But i guess it could be also a matter of user preferences of how you like do debug your code compared to the builded project

Comment: Possibly, but I'm more inclined to call this a bug in the conversion process, since it can't possibly succeed with both of these options enabled.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are choosing "Edit and Continue" (`/ZI`) to be able to fix code during debugging, but also "Disable Function-Level Linking" (`/Gy-`).

Those two will not work together, as you cannot just change one function in the middle of the code. So just choose one of them, like changing `/Gy-` to `/Gy`.

Comment: where are all those abbreviations described to understand which abbrev means what?

Comment: Here, see left side of this webpage. Although they didn't summarize everything in a single table: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=msvc-170

Comment: The above link from @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp is in German. Here's the English one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 118):

In the Configuration Properties (`Project ➔ Properties`),

"/ZI" is in

```
C/C++ ➔ General ➔ Debug Information Format
```

"/Gy" is in

```
C/C++ ➔ Code Generation ➔ Enable Function-Level Linking
```

Comment: @T.Todua see all options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 15):

*the same issue got, resolved by changing*

Project ➔ Properties ➔ C/C++ ➔ General ➔ Debug Information Format ➔ Program Database (/Zi)